# Do work without blocking the gui thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a c# windows forms application and use a library which does not provide async-await functionality.

When I press on a button I want to do some work (webrequesting).
While doing this work I dont want to freeze my gui.

I tried several approaches, for example:

```
public static Task<bool> LoginUser(string username, string password)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            session = new AuthenticatedSession<User>(new User(username), Cryptography.GetMd5(password));

            return true;
        }
        catch (InvalidAuthenticationException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

When I call `LoginUser("foo", "bar").Result` the gui freezes until the work is done (I understand that this is not async because I can't await `new AuthenticatedSession<..`.

So I look for something like:

1. Create a thread with a action as parameter
2. Return the value from the thread
3. End the thread

Comment: Does the library provide methods using the [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (aka `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`)? Are you on .Net 4.5 or higher? Have you looked at [continuations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? We *really* need to know more about your development environment to help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forcing a new thread (or WorkerThread) instead of using the TaskFactory.

```
Thread t = new Thread (delegate()
{
    try
    {
        session = new AuthenticatedSession<User>(new User(username), Cryptography.GetMd5(password));
        Success();  //coded below
    }
    catch (InvalidAuthenticationException)
    {
        Fail();
    }     
});
t.Start();
```

Your list requires that we return a value, all we really can do is call a method or set state indicating the return value or even signal (ManualResetEventSlim) if you want some blocking, but your requirements state you want non-blocking.

To resume execution or signal the GUI that your process is done you would invoke some method on the UI thread, like this:

```
void Success() {
  Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    SomeMethodOnTheUI();
  });
}
```

This is basically an async/callback strategy.

Comment: Note that OP's issue have nothing to do with starting the thread, but rather with wrong way of waiting for result (`.Result` on UI thread). So unless you explain magical `Success()` function (including `Invoke`) I don't think this would help OP.